# Shiro permission configuration and custom filter conflict

Tags: shiro

if I add a custom filter jwt to `shiroFilterFactoryBean`, the `urlFilter.put("/helloworld","authc,rolse[user]");` is
Invalid.

```
Map<String,Filter> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
filterMap.put("jwt",new JWTFilter() );

shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilters(filterMap);
Map<String,String> urlFilter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
urlFilter.put("/user/signin", "anon" );
urlFilter.put("/user/register", "anon" );
urlFilter.put("/**", "jwt" );
urlFilter.put("/helloworld", "authc,rolse[user]");
```

Comment: please ask an actual question. If you are looking for debugging help, describe the expected behavior, the actual one and your attempts to deal with the issue

Answer (score 0):

Order matters, you just need to stick the `/**` at the end of your map, see related warning in the documentation: 
https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#web-ini-configuration

Comment: but if i stick the /** at the end of my map,                                                                                    urlFilter.put("/helloworld", "authc,rolse[user]");                                                                            urlFilter.put("/**", "jwt" );                                                                                                                 the request will intercepted by authc,rolse[user] and not get into JWT filter